# What is the regex to replace a single space between a closing brace and a letter?

Tags: python, regex, sympy, regexp-replace

I want to replace all occurrences of

- case 1: a single space between 2 letters
- case 2: a single space between a closing brace `}` and a letter

with `\times` such that

```
'a^{3} + 3 a^{2} b + 3 a b^{2} + b^{3}'
```

becomes

```
'a^{3} + 3 \\times a^{2} \\times b + 3 \\times a \\times b^{2} + b^{3}'
```

I can successfully do the first case with `\b\s\b` but I don't know how to do for the second one.

My attempt below just produces

```
'a^{3} + 3 \\times a^{2}  b + 3 \\times a \\times b^{2} + b^{3}'
```

where  I fail to put `\\times` between `a^{2}` and `b`.

```py
import re
import sympy
from IPython.display import display
a,b = sympy.symbols('a b')

f = (a+b)**3
expr = sympy.latex(f.expand())
display(expr)
expr = re.sub(r'(\b\s\b)|(IDONTKNOW)', r' \\times ', expr)
display(expr)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
re.sub(r'(?<=[}\w])\s(?=\w)', r' \times ', expr)
```

The lookarounds are assertions which do not include the text in the match. `(?<=...)` requires the text before the main match to be either `}` or an alphanumeric, and `(?=...)` requires the text after the main match to be an alphanumeric.

(`\w` is not exactly "an alphanumeric"; it matches numbers and underscores in addition to alpbabetics. Probably replace it with e.g. `[A-Za-z]` if you strictly need to match only English alphabetics.)

Comment: Note: Changing `\\times` to `\times` will cause an issue for `display(Math(expr))`.

Comment: Is there any reason for even changing the right `\b` after `\s` to a lookahead?

Comment: @bobblebubble In this case mainly just orthogonality between the lookbehind and the lookahead, though also if you wanted something more specific than `\w`, the `\b` would no longer be correct.